# $ (dollar) sign in front of a class method name?

Tags: orders, payment, ee-1.13

In `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment::_void()`, there is a `$` sign placed like below.

```
$this->getMethodInstance()->setStore($order->getStoreId())->$gatewayCallback($this);
```

What is this doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php#L1139-L1141

There is an argument $gatewayCallback passed to the _void method, this argument is a string.

So when you see something like this: `$object->$variable();`
and `$variable = 'foo';`
The following code is called: `$object->foo();`

In this case it calls the `void` method of the payment gateway by default (as you can see in the function definition).